# UITableView reload not adding rows at the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I used the following code to insert the `row` always at the top and to reload data in `UITableView`. But it does not adding `row` at the top.

```
car = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"volvo",@"volvo1", nil];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [car count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [car objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


if(!indexPath.row == 0)
{

[self.tableview beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *indexpath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray *indextoadd = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexpath1];

[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indextoadd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableview endUpdates];
[self.tableview reloadData];

}

return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem you are getting ... cellForRowAtIndexPath will always call for show cells ...

Comment: its keep on loading the uitable. I just want to insert a new row at top from the NSMutableArray values and stop after all the values had been updated

Comment: The problem is because of writing `[self.tableview reloadData];` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: remove [self.tableview reloadData]; methode

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - where to call it? can u suggest me with code

Comment: @Balaji You need to reload table when you add or remove something from NSArray, and also outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. If you put that inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will keep calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Ok.. if i want to reload uitableview after i insert the data waht should i do.. I dont want reload tableview after any actions like selecting row. I just want to reload tableview immediately after the values assigned to cell. Is it possible

Comment: @Balaji What do you mean by `reload tableview immediately after the values assigned to cell`. I think you need to learn basics of UITableView. ReloadData reload your tableView with your new values. There is no need to reload table in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Sorry.. I mean that i want to reload tableview immediately after the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is it possible

Comment: @Balaji My friend go and learn the basics of UITableView.

Comment: updated my question. Have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this code:

```
[self.tableview beginUpdates];
 NSIndexPath *indexpath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
 NSArray *indextoadd = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexpath1];

[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indextoadd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableview endUpdates];
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and place it somewhere else.

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

is designated to create or dequeue a cell, it's not a place to insert objects into arrays and reload tables

Comment: if i place it somewhere else. Then how it reloads data in uitableview

Comment: why do you need to reload a table while creating its cells?

Comment: I have a array which has some car names. Now i want to display the car names at top row in tableview. So...

Comment: Instead of adding rows, you should be modifying your data source and reload table view.

Comment: So why not show the table view with its full content with car names from the very beginning? why fill array and reload the table when you actually build it? go on, make an array, fill it with everything that you need, then show the table view. that's it

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I want to reload table immediately after the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is it possible?

Comment: why on earth do you want it? what for?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha because i am loading array values from server so it will change dynamically

Comment: )))))) what you should do is add objects into array and reload the table when you receive new value from server. It has nothing to do with creating a new cell. The algorithm is the following 1) you get a new piece of data from the server 2) you add new data to the array 3) you reload the table.

Comment: @Balaji but why you write car array as fixed? You said you'd receive the items from server - post that code. Also I told you to remove updating code from cellForRowAtIndexPath but you didn't do that

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Thats ok.. Now I am asking that if i have the car array as fixed, is it possible to add rows at top. If yes can u tell me how

Comment: @Balaji to add rows at top you need to add new object to the beginning of the array and reload the table. the newly added object will be displayed on top

Comment: But if i add new object for the array, Will it have the old values in it. Can u provide me some codes or samples

Comment: Of course it will. say you have your array like car = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"volvo",@"volvo1", nil]. Then you do [car insertObject:@"audi" atIndex:0];. Now your array looks like @[@"audi", @"volvo",@"volvo1"] so when you reload the table audi is on top

Comment: can u provide me your contact details, i would like to be your friend